# Workaround needing multiple mutable references

Tags: rust, reference, borrow-checker

I am trying to implement a cli [blackjack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackjack) game in Rust. At the end of each round I want to calculate the winning player and move the cards in each player (including the winner)'s `hand` into the winners `won_hand` field.

The project structure has a `Table` struct which holds `players` and a `deck` (`Vec<Card>`). A Player has a `hand` field containing their current cards, `won_cards` which contains all the cards they have won in the game , status, etc.

The logic to calculate the winner is a method on `Table`. It returns a mutable reference because I want to append to the winner's `won_cards` field:

```rust
/// The current winning player at the table, or None if all players are bust.
pub fn winner(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Player> {
    self.players
        .iter_mut()
        .filter(|p| p.stat != PlayerStat::Bust)
        .max_by(|p1, p2| p1.hand_worth().cmp(&p2.hand_worth()))
}
```

there is also a helper method to collect the cards out of all the players' hands:

```rust
pub fn collect_cards(&mut self) -> Vec<Card> {
        let mut cards = vec![];
        for player in self.players.iter_mut() {
            cards.append(&mut player.hand);
        }

        cards
}
```

So I could collect the cards and *then* calculate the winner, which is what I have right now:

```rust
let mut drawn_cards = table.collect_cards();
let winner = match table.winner() {
    Some(w) => w,
    None => {
        println!("All players are bust!");
        println!("All cards will be reshuffled into the deck.");
        table.deck.append(&mut drawn_cards);
        table.deck.shuffle(&mut thread_rng());

        wait_for_enter();
        continue;
    }
};

println!("The winner is... {}!", winner.name);
winner.won_cards.append(&mut drawn_cards);
```

But the problem with that is when I call `winner()` all the player's hands have already been emptied by `collect_cards`, meaning the result will be wrong.

I can't call `winner` before `collect_cards` because then to use the mutable reference to append the drawn cards to the winner's hand I'd have multiple mutable references at once.

I'm stuck as to how to work around this, is it even possible to do cleanly or would I have to do some restructuring first?

Comment: @phimuemue Since the winner and other players are all under the same field `players`, I don't think that is any use here. Maybe I could try something like have an extra field `winner` on Table and update that instead of returning the reference..

Comment: I think your code is too complex and in too much of an OOP style for mutable references. I'd probably use a reference counter with interior mutability like `Rc<RefCell<Player>>`  or similar for handling player references.

Comment: I would just use indices.

Comment: Can you possibly just collect the cards *and* determine the winner *in one single method*?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions <3. I think I'm going to try learning a bit more about rust, smart pointers and stuff and come back to this later. I was sort of hoping I was missing something simple but it's fine.